# Does making games within games belong here or on Gamedev?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

With games like Little Big Planet, Garrys Mod, and now Project Spark I think we will start getting more questions making games using these games. I've never played little big planet so I don't know how in-depth it is, but the whole "game" of Project Spark (which I do play) is making games and will definitely raise some questions on "how to do X".

I see a some of meta threads about this already but those are specific to parts of a game (example minecraft computercraft coding)

This is also my first meta question so feel free to tear it apart, heh.

Comment: I can't seem to find a specific dupe, but essentially, it boils down to whether the dev tools are in the game, or a separate program.  Making levels in Little Big Planet?  On-topic.  Making a map in Starcraft?  Off-topic, because it's a separate program.

Comment: @Frank - Wow really? So programs like FarCry2's level creator is off-topic simply becuase it's a different executable?

Comment: If I had to argue for vs against, I'd say separate executable level editors classify as 'Game Specific Utilities'. Which are very much on-topic

Comment: @Robotnik The external program is right where the line is between expert and incidental knowledge.

Comment: @Frank - You could argue 'expert vs incidental knowledge' with any side-function within or out of a game, and I don't think it's a good measure of determining whether a game-specific function is on-topic or not. I fail to see how a separate executable (which gets a shortcut on the desktop just like the main one) is any different from clicking it in-game. Should we also argue expert vs incidental for the separate CoD multiplayer exe?

Comment: A better example: How about the Steam desktop client? technically I never have to use it, I can just launch steam game shortcuts. Or I could use it, and have knowledge about it. Yes its incidental knowledge, but why should that matter?

Comment: I don't think these kind of questions will be in the scope of Gamedev's tho.

Comment: We can't speak for Gamedev.

Comment: @badp - [They can speak for themselves](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/58/do-mod-and-map-making-questions-belong-here). (Although the discussion is as old as the one Less closed this question as). Might be worth bringing up with the mods there to make sure this is still the case?

Comment: the duplicate question is not related to this question. I'm talking about complete game making games, not mods or mod tools, like Project Spark and little big planet. For example, Project Spark has Brains/Kode to modify object behaviors, but it's not lines of code, but drag n drop tiles... very game-y, but still complex and raises questions (I already have a few...)